# Python Bottle template issue: AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute 'city'",)

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

As a learning project, I'm using MongoDB with Bottle for a web service. What I want to do is fetch results from MongoDB and display them in a template.  Here's the output I want from my template:

```
output.tpl
<html><body>
%for record in records:
   <li>{{record.city}} {{record.date}}
%end
</body></html>
```

I can pull the data out no problem:

```
result = db.records.find(query).limit(3)
return template('records_template', records=result)
```

But this resulted in no output at all - some debugging shows me that result is some sort of cursor:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x1560dd0>
```

So I attempted to convert this in to something that the template would like:

```
result = db.records.find(query).limit(3)
viewmodel=[]
for row in result:
  l = dict()
  for column in row:
    l[str(column)]=row[column]
  viewmodel.append(l)
return template('records_template', records=viewmodel)
```

Debugging shows me that my view data looks OK:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('4fe3dfbc62933a0338000001'),
  'city': u'CityName',
  'date': u'Thursday June 21, 2012'},
 {'_id': ObjectId('4fe3dfbd62933a0338000088')
  'city': u'CityName',
  'date': u'Thursday June 21, 2012'},
 {'_id': ObjectId('4fe3dfbd62933a0338000089')
  'city': u'CityName',
  'date': u'Thursday June 21, 2012'}]
```

But this is the response I'm getting. Any ideas why?

> AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute 'city'",)

Edit: I added that bit about l[str(column)]=row[column] to convert the dictionary keys to non-unicode strings in case that was the problem, but it doesn't seem to matter either way.

Comment: Have you tried using dictionary syntax? Example: `{{record['city']}} {{record['date']}}`

Comment: Just to go back to your original findings, do you have to convert it from a cursor a dictionary before sending to the template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the dictionary syntax to lookup the properties:

```
{{record['city']}} {{record['date']}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
result = db.records.find(query).limit(3)
viewmodel=[]
for row in result:
  l = dict()
  for column in row:
    l[str(column)]=row[column]
  viewmodel.append(l)
return template('records_template', records=viewmodel)
```

could be summarized in :

```
result = db.records.find(query).limit(3)
return template('records_template', records=list(result))
```

Python's beauty...